# Laravel cron error on mac osx

Tags: php, macos, cron

i'm just trying to use task schedule in my project, but when i using cron, the laravel command is not working. I try to catch the error with log file, and this is what i found.

```
Parse error: parse error in /Users/username/Sites/application-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

Everytime the cron is running, its always add this error to the log file, no other details. I try to run the command manually with this command

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

The command is working. Then i try to run the project on linux (ubuntu), and its work too! So what is the problem and how to fix it ??

This is my crontab

```
* * * * * php ~/Sites/application-name/artisan schedule:run >> /Users/username/Sites/schedule.log 2>&1
```

And this is my schedule function

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('data:get')->everyTenMinutes();
}
```

I'm using mac osx sierra 10.12.6 and run the project with serv command.

```
php artisan serv
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

helpers.php

```
232 if (is_string($arguments[0])) {
233    return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);
234 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I change the cron to this

```
* * * * * php --version $HOME/Sites/application-name/artisan schedule:run >> /Users/username/Sites/cron.log 2>&1
```

and this is the output.

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I'm using php 7.1 for the project, but cron using php 5.6. How to change it ??

**UPDATE 3**

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2017 15:02:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

**SOLVED**

I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/crontab-on-mac) solution at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/crontab-on-mac). When i change the cron and add the full path of php, its work!

Comment: What's on line 233 of the file in the error message?

Comment: I suspect you're using a different version of PHP when you run the script from `cron`, since `cron` doesn't use your `.profile` or `.bashrc` scripts.

Comment: Try putting `php --version` in `crontab` and doing that from the terminal.

Comment: [https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/installing-php71-with-homebrew/](https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/installing-php71-with-homebrew/) this might help

Comment: @Barmar thanks for help!

Comment: @JessieBaltazar you too, thanks!